# How does levelspec work inside Position?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Please, can you explain the following feature of levelspec inside Position ?

This code

```
test=Range[5];
Position[test,x_/;x>2]
```

as expected, gives

```
{{3},{4},{5}}
```

Similarly, this other one

```
test={"a","b","c"};
Position[test,x_/;StringFreeQ[x,"a"]]
```

should return

```
{{2},{3}}
```

and it does, but, further, prints a message:

```
StringFreeQ::strse: "String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringFreeQ[List,"a"]
```

My first conjecture was: "Well, Position firstly checks `test` as whole  (and here comes the message, because the head is `List`) then, in turn, each subexpression" .

But it seems that the explanation fails: the following instructions behave exactly as described above:

```
Position[test,x_/;StringFreeQ[x,"a"],1]
Position[test,x_/;StringFreeQ[x,"a"],{1}]
Position[test,x_/;StringFreeQ[x,"a"],2]
```

moreover

```
Position[test,x_/;StringFreeQ[x,"a"],{2}]
```

returns

`{}` .

I will be greatly grateful for any hints about all that.

Comment: `test = {"a", "b", "c"};
Position[test, x_ /; StringFreeQ[x, "a"], Heads -> False]`

Comment: "With the default option setting Heads->True, Position includes heads of expressions and their parts. "

Comment: Thanks for your replies !
I feel like I'm still missing the main point : at a foundamental level, 'Heads->False' makes Position "skips" the heads  taking into account their position  ( as seen using TreeForm ) or a   by means of  subtler algorithm ? In the first case, why 'Position[test, x_ /; StringFreeQ[x, "a"], {2}]' gives' {}' ?

Comment: @mitochondrial because there is nothing at level 2, your expression only has elements at level 0 and 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Depth-first searching

Let's test stuff out with a more complex example:

```
t = {"a", "b", "c", {"d", {"deep"}}, "e"};
Position[t, x_ /; (Print[x]; StringFreeQ[x, "a"])]
```

> List
>   a
>   b
>   c
>   List
>   d
>   List
>   deep
>   {deep}
>   {d,{deep}}
>   e
>   {a,b,c,{d,{deep}},e}
>
> ```
> {{2}, {3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {5}}
> ```

I omit the error messages, but they occur after each `List`. As per the docs, `Position` does a depth-first search. Thus, it checks from left to right, and as soon as it encounters an element in the list with "depth" it stalls on it and checks it down to the bottom. The sequence of positions checked is thus:

```
{{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2}, {4}, {5}, {}}
```

In other words, first the sub-parts of an expression are checked, then the expression as a whole is checked, as can be seen by the sequence `{4, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2}, {4}` where `{4}` comes last. The very last one to be checked is the entire expression `t`, which is designated by `{}` (again, see docs).

Now your first conjecture was that `Position` checks `test` (or `t` in my example) as a whole first, but that's not true. And it also wouldn't yield an error, as your `test` was indeed a list of strings, as the error message asks for. Indeed, as the output above shows, it checks the **head** of the expression first, which is also located at level 1, specifically at position 0. Because `{"a", "b", "c"}` is nothing more than `List["a", "b", "c"]`, `Position` simply goes through `List`, `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, and then finally `List["a", "b", "c"]`. For example:

```
Position[a[b, c, d], x_ /; (Print[x]; True)]
```

> a
>   b
>   c
>   d
>   a[b,c,d]
>
> ```
> {{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {}}
> ```

### Level specification

Now that the order of traversing through the list is cleared up, the levelspec behavior should be easy enough. In your case

```
Position[test,x_/;StringFreeQ[x,"a"],1]
Position[test,x_/;StringFreeQ[x,"a"],2]
```

are equivalent, because you only have one level in the expression. It is **not** equivalent to

```
Position[test,x_/;StringFreeQ[x,"a"]]
```

because this checks also level 0, while the above two expression do not. So compare the output at the top to the output of

```
Position[t, x_ /; (Print[x]; True), 1]
```

> List
>   a
>   b
>   c
>   {d,{deep}}
>   e
>
> ```
> {{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}
> ```

The entire expression is now absent, and so are the deeper levels of the 4th element.

```
Position[t, x_ /; (Print[x]; True), 2]
```

> List
>   a
>   b
>   c
>   List
>   d
>   {deep}
>   {d,{deep}}
>   e
>
> ```
> {{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4}, {5}}
> ```

Now only `"deep"` is absent (as is the entire expression), but note the `{"deep"}` is present.

Finally, these three commands give:

```
Position[t, x_ /; (Print[x]; True), {2}]
Position[t, x_ /; (Print[x]; True), {3}]
Position[t, x_ /; (Print[x]; True), {4}]
```

> List
>   d
>   {deep}
>
> ```
> {{4, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}}
> ```
>
> List
>   deep
>
> ```
> {{4, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 1}}
> ```
>
> '
>
> ```
>  {}
> ```

Note how nothing is printed for the last command: no elements at level 4 means nothing is checked at all.

Comment: Excellent answer!