# Setting depth on a pure function condition within Position

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I want to select points from a list that are within a certain region. Here's a MWE of my attempt:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}};
Position[pts, _?(RegionMember[Disk[{0, 0}], #] &)]
(*I want to output {{1},{2}} here*)
```

Unfortunately, this generates errors as instead of looking at the three points, it considers each coordinate in each point separately. How can I modify the code to have it consider the points?

Comment: For more in depth explanation see also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96245/how-does-levelspec-work-inside-position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a levelspec as third argument to `Position` to let it only consider the first level.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}};
Position[pts, _?(RegionMember[Disk[{0, 0}], #] &), {1}]
```

In this case this is equivalent to

```
Position[pts, _?(RegionMember[Disk[{0, 0}], #] &), 1]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks--was unaware of this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead use the single argument form of [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember)  and [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick):

```
pts = {{0,0}, {1/2,1/2}, {1,1}};

Pick[
    Range@Length @ pts,
    RegionMember[Disk[]] @ pts
]
```

> {1, 2}

`RegionMember[Disk[]] @ pts` will be much faster than evaluating `RegionMember[Disk[], pt]` for each point.

Comment: I'm going to accept the levelspec answer because I think it's more direct. But you're certainly correct about the timing. Finding 260 supermarkets in Chicago out of 24620 total in the dataset timed to 3.17188 with `Position` and only 0.016 with your approach! Thanks for the pro tip!